# Do you need java 6 to make Android applications?

Tags: android

I'm installing it using this guide here which asks me to install Java 6, but Oracle no longer allows you to download the version I'm supposed to get. Is it possible for me to just use Java 7, or will things begin to fail?

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2302780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you confusing the Java Runtime Engine (JRE) with the Java SDK? I can download Java 1.6 from the official source [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html).

You can also use Java 1.7 with Eclipse or Android Studio, so I'm pretty sure you accidentally went to the JRE download page. JRE and Java SDK ain't the same at all.

Comment: I very well may be! That link you provided even has the file I was meant to download from the guide. Thank you very much!